# Google Voice Java API ClientLogin Not Found

Tags: java, api, google-voice

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin - Not Found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.techventus.server.voice.exception.AuthenticationException.throwProperException(AuthenticationException.java:43)
at com.techventus.server.voice.Voice.login(Voice.java:1977)
at com.techventus.server.voice.Voice.init(Voice.java:418)
at com.techventus.server.voice.Voice.<init>(Voice.java:307)
at VoiceMain.main(VoiceMain.java:9)
```

Is the error I'm getting when I try to run this code (error occurs when I initialize a Voice object).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.techventus.server.voice.*;
public class VoiceMain {   
private static String username = "fakeemail@gmail.com";
private static String password = "xxxxxx"; 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Voice phone = new Voice(username, password);
    phone.sendSMS("xxx-xxx-xxxx", "Hello, this is google voice in java!");
}
}
```

I've downloaded all the dependencies, and I can't seem to find much documentation of an error like this anywhere online. Does anyone have experience with this API and know why I can't simply initialize a Voice object?

Edit: I've read that these methods and whatnot are now all deprecated, so how could I connect to google voice today? I'm inexperienced with OAuth2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same problem just using a raw HTTP request, without the Java API Voice object. It means that Google has apparently disabled that particular endpoint for POST requests and by extension, they've also disabled this hack. Short version: you and I will sadly have to move to Twilio for this functionality.